# What is a better way to remove element from a string and join it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, join, split

Is there a better way to do this using chaining?

```
var url = "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1"
var x = url.split('/');
console.log(x);
var y = x.pop();
console.log(y,x);
var z = x.join("/");
console.log(z);
```

I tried something like but wouldn't work since pop just returns the last value and not the rest:

```
parentUrl = self.attr('Url').split("/").pop().join("/");
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Chaining for the sake of chaining :) `url.split('/').filter(function(_, i, arr){return i< arr.length - 1;}).join('/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly do this with a regex replacement:

```js
var url = "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1";

var z = url.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '');

console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 3):

This Regex should do the trick:

```js
var url = "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1"
console.log(url.match(/^(.+)\/(.+)/));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using lodash. The `_.initial()` does exactly what I'm looking for.

```
var url = "www.mycompany.com/sites/demo/t1";
var x = _.initial(url.split("/")).join('/');
console.log(x);
```

The regex solutions worked as well. However, I don't know how to read regex yet so I didn't feel comfortable using something I didn't really understand. But they work so thanks.

EDIT: My project already has the lodash library so I'm not adding a library just for this :)